# Enable mod_header in apache in Mac OS X for CORS

Tags: apache, cors

I'm trying to set up my site to allow CORS for cross domain scripting, however this seems to require `mod_header` to be enabled in my .htaccess file. I don't have much experience dealing with apache.

I tried to google `installing mod_header in apache on mac os` but couldn't find any.

I tried this `user@mymac:~$ httpd -l` and here are the modules currently installed.

```
  core.c
  prefork.c
  http_core.c
  mod_so.c
```

Is anyone with knowledge able to tell me how to install `mod_header` in Mac OS?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you're referring [`mod_headers`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html). Normally it's already installed as shared module in apache.

Try this:

```
$ httpd -M |grep header
```

You should see:

```
Syntax OK
 headers_module (shared)
```

If not, go to `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`, find line below and uncomment it

```
# LoadModule headers_module libexec/apache2/mod_headers.so
```